# Finding the average and displaying the max data from csv(list indices must be integers or slices, not str) #python

Tags: python

New to python and was wondering how to solve my problem, I can't seem to solve it.

If a user selects a sector (e.g. Public or Private) and a 5-year span
[2010 - 2014], [2015 – 2019],
a) display the average number of doctors in the 5-year span.
b) display the maximum number of doctors in that period and the
year that the maximum occurs.

Based on user selection:

```
         elif sel == "B" or sel == "b":
print("="*50)
print("The average within a 5 years and when the maximum no.of dcotor occurs")
Sector = input("Please select the sector: ")
YearStart = input("Please the starting year: ")
if Sector.upper() == "Public Specialist":
    Sector = 1
elif Sector.upper() == "Public Non-Specialist":
    Sector = 2
elif Sector.upper() == "Private Specialist":
    Sector = 3
elif Sector.upper() == "Private Non-Specialist":
    Sector = 4
for k in range(1,11):
    if YearStart  == data[k][0]:
        for j in range(1,6):
            Total += int(data[j][Sector])
        break
    else:
        k += 1
Year = k
Average = Total/5
print(f"The average no.of doctors from {data[k][0]} - {data[k+5][0]} is {Average:.2f}")
```

My csv data

```
 Year,Public Specialist,Public Non-Specialist,Private Specialist,Private  Non-Specialist
 2010,1996,3184,1151,2159
 2011,2165,3456,1229,2220
 2012,2342,3789,1293,2222
 2013,2511,4150,1351,2327
 2014,2829,4501,1411,2379
 2015,3052,4857,1470,2444
 2016,3299,5059,1485,2494
 2017,3523,5050,1528,2579
 2018,3741,5078,1565,2660
 2019,3864,5166,1682,2757
```

My issue is that is shows "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: `Sector.upper() == "Public Specialist"` cannot ever be true because `"Public Specialist"` is not in upper case. That would be `"PUBLIC SPECIALIST"`. Similarly for the other conditions.

Comment: ohhh i see thanks very much, didn't realise my mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Given the .csv data you have shown in your question:

```
   Year  Public Specialist  Public Non-Specialist  Private Specialist  Private  Non-Specialist
   2010               1996                   3184                1151                     2159
   2011               2165                   3456                1229                     2220
   2012               2342                   3789                1293                     2222
   2013               2511                   4150                1351                     2327
   2014               2829                   4501                1411                     2379
   2015               3052                   4857                1470                     2444
   2016               3299                   5059                1485                     2494
   2017               3523                   5050                1528                     2579
   2018               3741                   5078                1565                     2660
   2019               3864                   5166                1682                     2757
```

It is clear that the way you are attempting to process the `Sector` value given at runtime is your main issue.

For example:

```py
if Sector.upper() == "Public Specialist":
    Sector = 1
```

Will never pass, as even in the case where `Sector = "Public Specialist"` this conditional will evaluate as follows:

```py
if "PUBLIC SPECIALIST" == "Public Specialist":
    Sector = 1
```

As the `str.upper()` function returns a fully capitalised string with the characters defined within `Sector`.

Because of this, `Sector` will always have the `str` value given by the user at runtime. When you hit this statement in your `for` loop further down:

```py
Total += int(data[j][Sector])
```

You will get an error thrown as your code is trying to access a list index using the `str` value assigned to `Sector`.

You may fix this by using:

```py
if Sector.title() == "Public Specialist":
    Sector = 1
# elifs using Sector.title() and current strings in your example for comparison
```

or

```py
if Sector.lower() == "public specialist"
    Sector = 1
# elifs using Sector.lower and lowercase strings for comparison
```

It may be worth checking out the [docs for `str` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) to develop a better understanding of `str` functions within Python.

#### Further Consideration

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the statement `k += 1` within this loop:

```py
for k in range(1,11):
    if YearStart  == data[k][0]:
        for j in range(1,6):
            Total += int(data[j][Sector])
        break
    else:
        k += 1
```

But just for you information, this is basically a wasted operation and is doing nothing to change or manipulate the value of `k` in any meaningful way at runtime.

The expression `range(1,11)` is only evaluated once, so changing the value of `k` within your loop is meaningless unless you are going to do some processing using the changed value within the iteration in which the value is changed. When the current iteration ends, `k` will become the next value as defined in the iterator created to define the bounds of the loop by `range(1,11)`.

I notice that you say that you're new to Python in your original question (willkómmen!) so I understand that you may think that this is how you need to iterate a `for` loop (i.e manually), you don't. `for k in range(1,11):` will iterate itself for values `k = 1` through `k = 10` for each iteration of the indented code directly following it without you having to increment it yourself using `k += 1`.

Hope this helps, best of luck :)

Comment: the year start is the input for example if i were to enter 2010 it will do 2010-2014 and find the average of data under public specialist